# Looping through repeating fields in FileMaker

Tags: loops, filemaker

NOTE: Please, no comments about whether or not you like repeating fields. That isn't the point of this question.

Is there a way to simplify this formula in FileMaker 10?

```
Substitute ( 
Trim ( 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[1]   & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[1]   & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[2]   & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[2]   & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[3]   & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[3]   & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[4]   & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[4]   & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[5]   & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[5]   & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[6]   & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[6]   & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[7]   & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[7]   & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[8]   & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[8]   & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[9]   & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[9]   & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[10] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[10] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[11] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[11] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[12] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[12] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[13] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[13] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[14] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[14] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[15] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[15] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[16] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[16] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[17] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[17] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[18] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[18] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[19] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[19] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[20] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[20] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[21] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[21] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[22] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[22] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[23] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[23] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[24] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[24] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[25] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[25] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[26] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[26] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[27] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[27] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[28] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[28] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[29] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[29] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[30] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[30] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[31] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[31] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[32] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[32] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[33] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[33] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[34] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[34] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[35] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[35] & ";" & 
Assortment Contents 3::Contents[36] & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty[36] & ";"
);
":;" ; "" )
```

Not every field repetition will be filled with content every time, which is why I am using Substitute to remove the excess punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start off by making a repeating calc field, let's call it Combined, this is equal to:

```
Assortment Contents 3::Contents & ":" & Assortment Contents 3::Content Qty
```

Then use the List function to get this as a return-separated list. After that it's just some text cleanup:

```
Substitute( Substitute( Trim( List( Assortment Contents 3::Combined ) ); "¶"; ";" ); ":;"; "" )
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I knew there had to be a better way! I had to make a couple tweaks. "List(Combined)", and added a semi-colon to the end since there isn't a ¶ to replace at the end)